# C# DateTime.Now different results in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime2

I have a SQL Server 2008 table with to different dates: `OrderDate` and `DeliveryDate`. I'm using Entity Framework 6.

Both fields are `datetime2(0)` type.

Here is how I'm creating my object before saving it to database:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

order.OrderDate = now;
order.DeliveryDate = isScheduled ? scheduledDate : order.OrderDate;
```

When I save it to database the dates are different, for example:

- OrderDate returns `2014-08-14 01:52:33`
- DeliveryDate returns `2014-08-14 01:52:31`

Already tried changing datetime2 precision from 0 to 7 with no luck.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Maybe `isScheduled` is `true` and it returns `scheduledDate` instead? Did you debug your code see their values?

Comment: Have you checked the table for triggers?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. 

@Johan There is no trigger in this table nor the whole database.

@SonerGönül When `isScheduled` returns true it is expected dates are different. The problem happens when it returns false and it's supposed to be the exactly same datetime.

Comment: Anyone can help, please? This is driving me crazy. :D